# SQL query to overlay date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date, range

Oracle 11i - looking for a query that will create a set of date ranges that let CUSTOM values override STANDARD values, and keep STANDARD values where they are not overridden.

```
STANDARD
CUSTOMER_ID  START_DATE  END_DATE     VALUE
0001         02/01/2013  09/15/2013   10

CUSTOM
CUSTOMER_ID  START_DATE  END_DATE     VALUE
0001         01/15/2013  03/15/2013   20
0001         07/01/2013  07/31/2013   30

Desired Result
CUSTOMER_ID  START_DATE  END_DATE     VALUE
0001         02/01/2103  03/15/2013   20
0001         03/16/2013  06/30/2013   10
0001         07/01/2013  07/31/2013   30
0001         08/01/2013  09/15/2013   10
```

Here are the results of the trial run:

```
select sc.customer_id, sc.thedate as start_date,
       lead(**sc.thedate**) over (partition by sc.customer_id order by sc.thedate) as end_date,
       sc.value
from (select customer_id, start_date as thedate, value
      from standard
      union all
      select customer_id, start_date, value
      from custom
      union all
      select s.customer_id, c.end_date + 1, s.value
      from custom c join
           standard s
           on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
      union all
      select customer_id, end_date, NULL
      from standard
     ) sc
where value is not NULL;

CUSTOMER_ID     START_DATE              END_DATE                VALUE
0001            15-JAN-13 12.00.00 AM   01-FEB-13 12.00.00 AM   20
0001            01-FEB-13 12.00.00 AM   16-MAR-13 12.00.00 AM   10
0001            16-MAR-13 12.00.00 AM   01-JUL-13 12.00.00 AM   10
0001            01-JUL-13 12.00.00 AM   01-AUG-13 12.00.00 AM   30
0001            01-AUG-13 12.00.00 AM                           10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach.  Break up the data into each date (for each customer) of when values start.  Then use Oracle analytic functions to bring the data together.  The dates are the start of the "value".  Then use `lead()` to get the next date.

```
select sc.customer_id, sc.thedate as start_date,
       lead(sc.start_date) over (partition by sc.customer_id order by sc.thedate) as end_date,
       sc.value
from (select s.customer_id, s.start_date as thedate, s.value
      from standard
      union all
      select c.customer_id, c.start_date, c.value
      from custom
      union all
      select s.customer_id, c.end_date + 1, s.value
      from custom c join
           standard s
           on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
      union all
      select s.customer_id, s.end_date, NULL
      from standard
     ) sc
where value is not NULL;
```

Note that this includes an extra record for the `end_date`, which you do not need as a final row.  This is tagged with a `NULL` value, which is filtered out in the outer query.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this solution and your SQL/Excel book on Amazon. Looks like it still gets good reviews after six or so years. Any recommended supplements?

Comment: added modifications and results to question @Gordon